# Sql How to increment a field in a Select

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a view from a simple `SELECT`.

```
SELECT NULL AS productcode
       , name 
  FROM item;
```

```
productcode    name
NULL           Toto
NULL           Titi
NULL           Tata
```

Instead of the null i'd like to get my product code (9000) from another table and increment it to get :

```
 productcode    name
 90001           Toto
 90002           Titi
 90003           Tata
```

Thank You

Comment: You are going to need another column which provides the ordering you showed us.  What I mean by this is, what determines the order `Toto Titi Tata` in the `name` column?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you can try to work on a query like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE P (product_code VARCHAR(10), NAME VARCHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE U (product_code VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO P VALUES (NULL,'Toto');
INSERT INTO P VALUES (NULL,'Titi');
INSERT INTO P VALUES (NULL,'Tata');
INSERT INTO P VALUES (1,'Prod1');

INSERT INTO U VALUES ('90000');  #THIS MUST HAVE ONLY ONE RECORD!


SELECT NEW_CODE, NAME 
FROM (
    SELECT P.NAME
    , @r:= @r+1 R
    , CONCAT(U.product_code,@r) NEW_CODE 
    FROM P 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r:=0) C
    CROSS JOIN U 
    WHERE P.product_code IS NULL
    ) Y;
```

Output:

```
    NEW_CODE    NAME
1   900001  Toto
2   900002  Titi
3   900003  Tata
```

Comment: This might be the only option- but note that in the absence of any order by clause, this method is unreliable. Of course in this a reverse alphabetical order is available- but that may just be coincidence

Comment: @Strawberry: it's now without any order (it has not been asked).  It's quite easy to add any order (eg. by Name: I already did some test with ORDER BY).

Comment: I wouldn't say "unreliable" but "non deterministic for same starting values".

Comment: Yes - in terms of human expectation, I'm not sure that there's much difference.

Comment: I think there's much difference.